# How can I make subviews of UIWebView with its web content?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, scroll

I added a button on UIWebView, but the button is stayed at the position while HTML content is scrolling. I want to make it scroll with HTML. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wait for iOS 5.0, UIWebView will have a UIScrollView subview so you can get the page offset and move the button in the ScollView Delegate methods.

Comment: This is very useful to me - can you cite where you got this info though?

Comment: @crimson_penguin From developer.apple.com, there is a pre-release library and a iOS5 API differs doc;-)

Comment: Well that makes sense. Thanks! I'm just gonna wait for iOS 5, since it should be soon.